# Using the networkmonitor alive check won't work

Tags: python, fuzzing, boofuzz

I'm trying to build a (protocol) fuzzer. For that I need to monitor if the target isn't crashed (separate device). To start simple, I've programmed a simple server (running on another machine) that will return an OK or a NOK, or closes its connection. This is working beautifully.

Now I've already build something that will fuzz the simple server, reads the response of the server (the OK and NOK), I want to monitor if the connection isn't closed, by trying to connect to it.

According the BooFuzz documentation (I'm using BooFuzz 0.4.2) it has to be done with the NetworkMonitor and its function alive(). I've used the example autoprog as basis and modified the monitor call, but it keeps mentioning IOT_TargetMonitor.**init**() is missing 1 required positional argument. I've tried adding the requested arguments (in this case the host and port), but no success. Am I missing someting?

The code I'm using at the moment:

The main routine:

```
def main():
   # Define the IOT_TargetMonitor
   IOT_TargetMonitor(host = g_target_ip_addr, port = g_target_port)

   # Create the session
   session = Session(
     target = Target(
       connection = TCPSocketConnection(host = g_target_ip_addr, port = g_target_port),
       monitors = [IOT_TargetMonitor],
       monitor_alive = [IOT_TargetMonitor], 
       ),
    )

    # A simple message that easily finds the bug in the simple server
    message1 = Request(
      "message1",
      children=(
        Simple(name="first_byte", default_value=b"\x01", fuzz_values=[b"6", b"B", b"C"]),
        Simple(name="second_byte", default_value=b"\x02", fuzz_values=[b"1", b"6", b"3"]),
        Simple(name="third_byte", default_value=b"\x03", fuzz_values=[b"@", b"#", b"6"]),
      ),
    )

    session.connect(message1)

    # sleep time between tests
    session.sleep_time = 0.01
    
    # after fuzzing, data is to be received. The response of my simple server
    session._receive_data_after_fuzz = True 
    
    # use only one target connection instead of reconnecting each test case
    session._reuse_target_connection = True
    
    # start fuzzing
    session.fuzz()
```

The main routine calls IOT_TargetMonitor:

```
class IOT_TargetMonitor(NetworkMonitor):
    global g_target_ip_addr
    global g_target_port
    
    def __init__(self, host, port):
        self.host = host
        self.port = port

    def alive():
        print("Checking if IOT device is alive.....")
        mylogger.log_info("Checking if IOT device is alive")
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        try:
            sock.connect((g_target_ip_addr, g_target_port))
            mylogger.log_pass(description="alive")
            return True
        except ConnectionRefusedError:
            mylogger.log_fail(description="Server down")    
            return False
```

All the other functions are overridden too, but contains just print commands

The (error) messages from the command prompt are:

```
[2023-10-15 13:39:01,970]     Info: Web interface can be found at http://localhost:26000
Checking if IOT device is alive.....
[2023-10-15 13:39:01,971]     Info: Checking if IOT device is alive
[2023-10-15 13:39:01,973]       Check OK: alive
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "y:\Python\TestFuzzer\test_boo.py", line 192, in <module>
    main()
  File "y:\Python\TestFuzzer\test_boo.py", line 145, in main
    session = Session(
              ^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Licensed User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\boofuzz\sessions\session.py", line 265, in __init__
    self.add_target(target)
  File "C:\Users\Licensed User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\boofuzz\sessions\session.py", line 303, in add_target
    target.monitors_alive()
  File "C:\Users\Licensed User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\boofuzz\sessions\target.py", line 135, in monitors_alive
    cb(monitor)
TypeError: IOT_TargetMonitor.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'port'
```